# dropdown_search search text filed is not showing

Tags: flutter, flutter-dropdownbutton

i ma trying to add searchable drop down box for my flutter application but when i add code from package example it's not showing the text filed for enter the values that i need to search ?
FYI
showSearchBox is depericiated since it's not letting me add that parameter.

this is the codes that i have been trying so far non of the is working

```
DropdownSearch<int>(
                      items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                      dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
                        dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Modal mode",
                          hintText: "Select an Int",
                          filled: true,
                        ),
                      ),
                      popupProps: PopupPropsMultiSelection.modalBottomSheet(
                        disabledItemFn: (int i) => i <= 3,
                      ),
                    ),
```

For this code i am getting the drop down but no text filed

[image]

[image]

but according the to the [package](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search) info i should see a text filed.

and after all i have tried with my own model when i do that still same result

```
 DropdownSearch(
        enabled: true,
        filterFn: (user, filter) {//this is just for testing i though if i add this then it will show the text filed
          print(filter);
           return true;},
          itemAsString: (item) =>"${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}",
         dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
              dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Menu mode",
               hintText: "country in menu mode",
              filled: true,),),
             items: studentController.studentList DropdownSearch(
                            enabled: true,
                            filterFn: (user, filter) {//this is just for testing i though if i add this then it will show the text filed
                              print(filter);
                              return true;
                            },
                            itemAsString: (item) =>
                                "${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}",
                            dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
                              dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: "Menu mode",
                                hintText: "country in menu mode",
                                filled: true,
                              ),
                            ),
                            items: studentController.studentList,
                          ),  ),
```

For this also i ma getting the same result

[image]

[image]

Comment: `showSearchBox: true,` add this property

Comment: yes i have tried that parameter showSearchBox is depreciated

Answer (score 2):

in the current version the `showSearchBox` property  found inside `popupProps`

```
DropdownSearch<Model>(
  popupProps: PopupProps.menu(
      fit: FlexFit.loose,
      showSearchBox: true, // add this line 
      title:
```

Comment: Thank you very much i have looked in there but couldn't find it.